# Complex SQL Query For Counting and Listing

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write complex sql for counting distinct names popularity and sorting them with descending order. I'll do this with hibernate @Query("SELECT * FROM ...") parameter. First I tried to do it on SQL then implement it to my spring boot project but I'm stuck while writing it.

```
SELECT
    f.Name,
    COUNT(SELECT * FROM Family g WHERE g.Name WHERE ???) AS numberOfCount

FROM Family AS f
ORDER BY numberOfCount
```

```
id  | Name     | Surname | 
--------------------------
1   | John     | Smith   | 
2   | Mary     | Smith   | 
3   | John     | Dawson  | 
4   | Lisa     | Smith   | 
5   | Lisa     | Dawson  | 
6   | Jack     | Smith   |
7   | John     | Smith   |
```

Sorted version:

```
 Name    | Popularity
--------------------------
| John   |  3
| Lisa   |  2
| Mary   |  1
| Jack   |  1
```

Comment: share your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [group by](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html). The query will look like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS popularity 
FROM test 
GROUP BY NAME 
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

The jpql should be like this:

```
@Query("SELECT t.name AS name, COUNT(t.name) AS popularity FROM Test t GROUP BY t.name ORDER BY popularity DESC")
```

Comment: The OP tagged `oracle-sqldeveloper` (presumably meaning they are using Oracle) which means lots of the syntax you use is invalid in Oracle (cannot have `AS` before a table alias and cannot use back-ticks around identifiers). You would want: `SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS popularity FROM test GROUP BY name ORDER BY popularity DESC`.

Comment: @MT0 I totally missed the tag, thanks the note and the query fix.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried with not showing count values on result so that I can store them in string list with using having key but it says there is syntax error. But I don't understand why

SELECT name FROM Test 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(name) AS popularity 
ORDER BY popularity DESC;

Comment: Oh, I have changed it like this and now it's working :) SELECT name FROM Test 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC;

Answer (score 1):

you can use **group by** for counting popularity and **distinct** for unique names

```
select distinct name, count(id) as pop from test group by name order by pop desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 'DISTINCT' will help you.

Example -

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, COUNT(ID) as ID_COUNT FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY ID and use `asc` or `desc` as your requirement.
```

`DISTINCT` - will give you unique name
`COUNT(ID)` - Will give you count of id's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).